# f(x) = $\int_a^x \int_a^x (f(t)*g'(t))/g(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I believe the above statement is true... but I'm not quite sure why.  I have tried using change of variables with f(a)=0, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Is the star multiplication or convolution?

Comment: @dcs24 multiplication

Comment: Try to expand the left integral using the quotient rule.

Comment: thank you @dcs24 - makes sense!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the two integrals, apply the quotient rule to $(f(t)/g(t))'$ and simplify your expression becomes:

$$f(x) = \int_a^{x} f'(t) dt$$

Which is certainly true if $f(a) = 0$.